# Spring context compile time validation

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, testing

Is there any tool or maven plugin that can validate Spring context during compile time or maven build execution?

I understand that it's not trivial to check the full correctness of the context without the app start, but it will be good to check some trivial cases, for example if you define a bean in xml context then the bean class have to be present in classpath.

Comment: You should use tests for that, during Maven test phase.

Comment: Yes, the desire is to execute it during Maven build phase, the question is - what exactly to execute. The @luboskrnac example looks good, I'll try that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides) contains such sanity test.

For Spring MVC should test with MockMvc test. To verify that Spring configuration is OK, you can Create full context and fire requests against URL and cover also validation + all the Spring wiring. Such test is executed during test maven phase.

Something like this:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RestApplication.class)
public class RestApplicationContextTest extends
    AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  private static final String FULL_USER_URL = "http://localhost:10403/users";
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void init() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  private static String createTestRecord(int identifier) {
    String testingRecordString =
        "{\"email\": \"user%d@gmail.com\", \"name\": \"User%d\"}";
    return String.format(testingRecordString, identifier, identifier,
        identifier);
  }

  @Test
  public void testPost() throws Exception {
    // GIVEN
    String testingRecord = createTestRecord(0);

    // WHEN
    // @formatter:off
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post(FULL_USER_URL)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(testingRecord))
        .andReturn();
    // @formatter:on

    // THEN
    int httpStatus = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
    assertEquals(httpStatus, HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
  }
  ...
```